# Trying to keep a simple 'count and mail' script running

Tags: bash

I am trying to learn bash scripting, and found some scripts online which I am editing. My goal: let the script check a webpage every 10 minutes to see if a specific word is present: if it is; all is fine and check again in 10 minutes.

If the word is missing, or the webpage is not loading: send a simple e-mail and check again in 10 minutes

The following script seems to do the job BUT it will stop when the word is missing and the e-mail is send.

I'm sure I am close, but can someone maybe help? :)

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ 1 ];
do
    count=`curl -s "MyURL" | grep -c "MyWORD"`

    if [ "$count" = "0" ]
    then
       echo "MyMAILBODY" | mail -s "MyMAILSUBJECT" MyFROMADDRESS
       exit 0   
    fi
    sleep 600
done
```

Comment: What if you actually count the results from the grep? `| grep -c "MyWord" | wc -l` Then at least you are sure the value will be zero if none is found.

Comment: You have used exit 0 which is a successfull exit code hence the shell wont reach the sleep 600 line. remove theexit 0 and it should work. My sugestion would be to use cron jobs instead of sleep statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactoring with the `exit 0` removed and some antipatterns fixed.

```
#!/bin/bash

# [ 1 ] happens to work but is silly
# -- it means "if 1 is not an empty string"
while true;
do
    # No need to figure out how many matches exactly
    # if all you care about is whether or not the word occurs.
    # Also no good reason to put the result in a variable.
    if ! curl -s "MyURL" | grep -q "MyWORD" 
    then
       echo "MyMAILBODY" | mail -s "MyMAILSUBJECT" MyFROMADDRESS
    fi
    sleep 600
done
```